# Rename an excel file while the file is open

Tags: excel, vba, file, rename

I wanted to know if it would be possible to rename an active/open workbook using VBA. The idea is to add "Completed" to the file name without creating another copy of the file.

I managed to write a code to re-save the file with completed added in front of the file name but the old file exists and when trying to remove the file using the Kill command it does not work which is probably due to the file still being open.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated....

Comment: You should be able to delete the original workbook after using `.SaveAs` .  Can you post your code?  This is assuming the file is not opened by another user or instance of Excel.

Comment: "I managed to write a code"  - always helps to post the code you're working on

Comment: Apologies for the late response, having looked further into this it seems the concept of renaming or deleting an open file while open would not work, Thank you for replying.